# What is the best way to copy the mongoDB collection to collection in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin

I have a scenario where I need to copy the mongoDB collection from one environment to another environment. This needs to be done on weekly basis. I was thinking to use change streams as a permanent solution. Can someone help me out what is the best solution for this usecase.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611576/spring-data-mongodb-copy-a-collection

Comment: @shridutt-kothari - is this the best practice to copy the collection very frequently. After first time copy can we use change streams ?

Comment: Its up to us, how we want to copy data, we can decide based on how much data is there and which approach is faster or suits our requirements, may be we can do some POC and find out which on is best for our requirements